# Python dict to select function runs all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

So I tried cutting down on nested if's by using a dict to select a function to run. When calling execute in a test I'm usually calling it with "execute("BACKUP","/home/src","/home/dest")"

But for some reason it runs both the BACKUP option twice. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python3

```
    def execute(jobtype, src, dst):
        if jobtype == "FULL":
            _o_src = fs.Index(src)
            fs.MakeFolders(_o_src.GetFolders(), dst)
            fs.MakeFiles(src, dst, _o_src.GetFiles())
        if jobtype == "INCREMENTAL":
                print("DO INCREMENTAL BACKUP " + src + " TO " + dst)
    # Do the things
    options = {
                "BACKUP": execute(self.jobtype, self.src, self.dst),
                "RESTORE": execute(self.jobtype, self.dst, self.src),
              }
    options[jobtype]()
```

Comment: ... because you are calling it twice...

Comment: Well, for starters, don't call the function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not storing your `execute` function in your `options` dict. You're storing the result of calling that function. And since it's the same function either way with different parameters being passed in, you don't actually need the function to be the values in your dict. You need the parameters. Change your last four lines to:

```
options = {
          "BACKUP": [self.jobtype, self.src, self.dst],
          "RESTORE": [self.jobtype, self.dst, self.src],
          }
execute(*options[jobtype])
```